# How do I get the value of expression string in sqlite within query?

Tags: sqlite

I want math expression string('(0.98/0.62)') in a column to be evaluated within query.

I expect "select '(0.98/0.62)'" to return 0.98/0.62=1.58... not '(0.98/0.62)'.

Comment: It seems you want to parse a string to a number.

Comment: Yes it is. I know it is not a normal operation in sqlite, I could not find any way.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, so it does not have any built-in mechanism to execute dynamic SQL.

It would be possible to [register a user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that executes an SQL expression.

Comment: Which means some logic will be required, will it be better to add a new column which hold resolved value? Plus database version update codes by parsing back those expression using java then update the new columns. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to evaluate that expression at *some* time. Moving that time around does not solve your original problem.

Comment: yes, I already have a method that solve in java but not in sql. Thanks.